# Convert for loop to while loop. I have the question at the very bottom since I couldn't come up with a better format for the question

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop

**3. Convert the following for loop to while loop**

```
    p=0
    for k in range (5,19,3):
        print("k=",k)
        p+=k
    else:
        print(k*2)
    print(p)
```

**Output**

```
k= 5
k= 8
k= 11
k= 14
k= 17
34
55
```

**My while loop**

```
def q3():
        k=5
        p=0
        while p<=55:
            print("k=",k)
            k+=3
            p+=k
        else:
            print(k*2)
        print(p)
```

**Output**

```
k= 5
k= 8
k= 11
k= 14
k= 17
40
70
```

**Question.**

In the last two lines of the for-loop
my output for
k x 2  was 34   (last k value generated=17 x 2)
print(p) was 55 (sum of all k values generated)

Whereas the last two lines of my while-loop
produced
k x 2: 40       (Why is it generating 40?)
print(p) was 70 (Again, why is it producing 70?)

Comment: `k+=3` is executed finally in the while-loop even if it is exited before the next iteration. Nothing similar happens in the for-loop.

Comment: That makes great sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Micheal mentioned the last `k +=3` statement in the while loop will be executed and then it will exit the loop. You need to either subtract your limit (i.e. 19) and initial value of k (i.e. 5) by 3, or reverse the last +3 operation by `k -=3`.

Solution 1:

```
p=0                                                                                                                          
k=2                                                                                                                          
while k < 16:                                                                                                                       
    k += 3                                                                                                                    
    p += k                                                                                                                   
    print("k =",k)                                                                                                           
else:                                                                                                                        
    print(k*2) 
print(p)
```

Solution 2:

```
p=0                                                                                                                          
k=5                                                                                                                          
while k < 19:                                                                                                                       
    print("k =",k)
    p += k                                   
    k += 3                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
else:   
    k -= 3                                                                                                                     
    print(k*2) 
print(p)
```

Answer (score 0):

after ending the loop in `for loop` the counter always is the last acceptable number which is 17, but in `while loop` we added 3 to the counter manually so after ending `while loop` the counter has its last modification value which is 20. that's why we should decrease k by three in line `print(k*2)`. also the line `else:` is redundant, so you can omit it.

```
print("for version")
p=0
for k in range (5,19,3):
    print("k=",k)
    p+=k
print(k*2)
print(p)

print("while version")
p=0
k=5
while k<19:
    print("k =",k)
    p += k
    k += 3
print((k-3)*2)
print(p)
```

Comment: you are welcome, don't forget to mark it as an accepted answer

Comment: It would even be more valuable if you would write a few explaining words.